# Referencing a file from within nuget dll

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a class library which I want to expose as a nuget package.

The class library I am creating, deserializes a couple of XML files and expose them as properties. So I am adding these xml files in the nuspec file:

```
<files>     
    <file src="..\config1.xml" target="Content\Config" />
    <file src="..\config2.xml" target="Content\Config" />
  </files>
```

so that the dll can read these files and expose them as properties to the consuming code.

The problem is when I install this NuGet package, the dll is unable to access these XML files.

What is the right way to handle this use case? To create the NuGet package?

Comment: Your library should adapt to .NET Framework/.NET Core's configuration system, instead of creating your own XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the XML file is included in your project, you can set the [Build Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2017#build-action-values) property of the XML file to "Embedded Resource". This says that:

> The file is passed to the compiler as a resource to be embedded in the
>   assembly.

See [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6990068d-ddee-41e9-86fc-01527dcd99b5/how-to-embed-xml-file-in-project-resources?forum=csharpgeneral) for more details.